# Determing caret position in tokenized html input?

Tags: javascript, html

**(no jquery please)**

Given an html input whose `value` is split by `/\s+/g`, how would you find the current token that the caret is positioned at?

For instance, if your input value is

```
abc      ab          monkey
```

And you split it, it will become

```
["abc, "ab", "monkey"]
```

But if your caret position in the input is here...

```
abc      ab        monk^(caret here)ey
```

How would you determine which token the caret is currently in?

The api I'm looking for would be something like

```
var currentToken = getPosition(inputEl.value); // { index: 2, token: "monkey" }
```

I have most of it down, but when I start backtracking inside the input with the left arrow it gets messed up.

http://jsfiddle.net/dlizik/zmbpq5hz/

**html**

```
<input id="input" />
<pre id="test"></pre>
cursor at current token: <span id="res"></span>
```

**js**

```
(function($doc) {
    "use strict";    

    var single = /\s/g;
    var spacer = /\s+/g;
    var disp = $doc.getElementById("test");
    var input = $doc.getElementById("input");
    var res = $doc.getElementById("res");

    function keyListen(e) {
        var tokens = this.value.split(spacer);
        var tokenLengths = tokens.map(function(i) { return i.length; });
        var cumulative = tokenLengths.map(function(i, n) {
            return tokenLengths.slice(0, n + 1).reduce(function(a, b) {
                return a + b;
            });
        });
        var cursor = caretPos(this);
        var currToken = tokens[getPos(cursor, cumulative)];
        res.textContent = currToken;
        disp.textContent = JSON.stringify(this.value.split(spacer), null, 2);
    }

    function getPos(curr, arr) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (curr <= arr[i]) return i;
        }
    }

    function caretPos(el) {
        var val = el.value;
        var extra = val.match(single);
        var whitespace = extra == null ? 0 : extra.length;
        var pos = 0;
        if ($doc.selection) {
            el.focus();
            var sel = $doc.selection.createRange();
            sel.moveStart('character', -val.length);
            pos = sel.text.length;
        }
        else if (el.selectionStart || el.selectionStart == '0') pos = el.selectionStart;
        return (pos - whitespace);
    }

    input.addEventListener("keyup", keyListen.bind(input), false);

})(document);
```

Comment: may sound novice, but could you not just replace multiple whitepaces with a single whitespace, and then split the string based on whitespace? then take the array and look for the "caret" and get your index if that char is in that index of the array?  --- after looking at your fiddle I'm assuming I'm not understanding your question

Comment: @RobScott that's basically what i'm attempting to do now, but adjusting the caret position via arrow keys results in some unpredictable behavior that I am not sure how to deal with

Comment: per your example string though all you're doing is splitting the string based on whitespace and if that index has the character, in this case the caret, then you lock that index down and pass it. is that not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you can just use regular expressions...wasn't that hard now that I think about it. You just have to find the number of words left of the caret position. That will give you the current token index as well as the string itself. However, you just have to account for a caret whose adjacent strings are both empty spaces.

http://jsfiddle.net/dlizik/zmbpq5hz/1/

This is the function you want to run

```
(function($doc) {
    "use strict";    

    var single = /\s/g;
    var tokenize = /[^\s+]/g;
    var ledge = /[\s]*[^\s]+[\s]*/g;
    var disp = $doc.getElementById("test");
    var input = $doc.getElementById("input");
    var res = $doc.getElementById("res");

    function keyListen(e) {
        var tokens = this.value.match(tokenize);
        var pos = caretPos(this);
        var adj = this.value.substring(pos - 1, pos + 1);
        var left = this.value.slice(0, pos + 1).match(ledge).length - 1;
        var curr = adj === "  " ? null : tokens[left];
        res.textContent = curr + "";
        disp.textContent = JSON.stringify(this.value.split(spacer), null, 2);
    }

    function caretPos(el) {
        var pos = 0;
        if ($doc.selection) {
            el.focus();
            var sel = $doc.selection.createRange();
            sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
            pos = sel.text.length;
        }
        else if (el.selectionStart || el.selectionStart == '0') pos = el.selectionStart;
        return (pos);
    }

    input.addEventListener("keyup", keyListen.bind(input), false);

})(document);
```